# Brother MFC6490CW Printer Drivers

Tags: 12.10, drivers, printing, brother

I have recently installed Ubuntu 12.10 and can not get my Brother MFC6490CW printer to work. When I try to install the device, Ubuntu does not find a driver.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, your printer is not supported in the `brother-lpr-driver` [package](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/BrotherDriverPackaging)

So you will have to download the driver directly from the [manufacturer's site](http://welcome.solutions.brother.com/bsc/public_s/id/linux/en/download_prn.html#MFC-6490CW)

- download both `.deb` files. See screenshot.

[image]

- Go through the usual license agreement bla bla...
- Open file manager and go to your Downloads folder.
- Double click the `.deb` file. It should be opened by "Software Center".
- Click install.
- Do the same for the other file.